# Django ModelForm: How to override or check for "save_as"

Tags: django, save, modelform, save-as

I need to add some customizations for the case that a instance in Django Admin is "saved_as" a copy. Can I do that in `save()`, if so how do I check for the `save_as kwarg`?
Or is there a `save_as()` method I can override somewhere. I was not able to find any information about the differences in the process between a regular `save()` and one with `save_as = True`.

Can someone point me to an example or give me an hint where to go?

Thank you very much for your time!

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

The Save as New button is a submit element with a specific name, `_saveasnew`, meaning you can check whether that button was pressed via the presence of the `_saveasnew` POST parameter.

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):        
    if '_saveasnew' in request.POST:
        # custom logic for save as new
        print "I am saved as new"
    return super(ModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```